# How select data where they have on second difference?

Tags: sql-server

I have table in SQL server and one column that contain time. here is my table:

```
 time          latitude   longitude  test
-------       --------   ---------- --------
17:25:47.3      35.40        50.50     10
17:25:47.10     35.40        50.50    -85
17:25:47.30     35.40        50.50     20
17:25:48.10     35.40        50.50     32
17:25:48.30     35.40        50.50     12
17:25:49        35.40        50.50      0
```

i need an SQL server query that return test values every one second.
the result must be like this:

```
 time          latitude   longitude  test
----------     --------   ---------- --------
17:25:47.3      35.40        50.50     10
17:25:48.3      35.40        50.50     32
17:25:49        35.40        50.50      0
```

Comment: What type is lat long ? float or geography ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir How will it affect the result in this case?

Comment: Calculations. if it's float then youll have to convert it to geography a

Comment: Based on OP's requirements, I think the latitude and longitude columns don't have to be processed. Will the query still be affected by what datatype they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your version of SQL Server supports `row_number` function, you can do the following:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by datediff(s,0,[time]) order by datepart(s,[time])) rn
from tablename)

select [time],latitude,longitude,test
from cte
where rn = 1
```

The idea is that we partition our data by the time and then get the first record within each 'group' (same hour,minute,second). Note that the argument 's' is passed to the `datediff` function. This ensures that the same value is returned for same combination of hour,minute,second even if millisecond values are different.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XDVIV4702)